# SASS. Use glob pattern with @use

Tags: npm, webpack, sass, gulp

I have 50+ .scss files in 5 folders and use webpack [plugin](https://github.com/maoberlehner/node-sass-magic-importer) to import all files from folder.

```
// index.scss
@import "default/*.scss";
@import "vendors";
@import "components/*.scss";
@import "modals/*.scss";
@import "pages/*.scss";
```

This plugin work well with @import, but can`t understand  @use. I think to extend plugin, but think if there is any other solution.